# Does Docusign offer 'placeholder' support for Text Tags?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I would like to add some placeholder text to assist the signer with what type of data they should populate. Although a nearby label is the main source of assistance/guidance, I was hoping to add some placeholder text as well. Looking through the documentation for ***Text*** I do not see such such an attribute. So if the ***Text*** class does not support 'placeholder text', is the next best thing the usage of ***tooltip*** argument?

Goal:

[image: Placeholder Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not exact equivalent feature. You can do these things, but none is exactly what you asked about:

- You can set the initial value of the text tab. This would not require the user to modify it and would not immediately be removed when they focus on that tab.
- You can use a tooltip like you mentioned.
- You can use a label like you mentioned.

In addition, you can use various validation rules to ensure user filled the tab correctly.